# Personal Gmail Google Doc Apps Script Will Not Allow Authorizing - This app is blocked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-apps-script-api

I can't seem to authorize a Google Doc Apps Script to run. When adding permissions Google keeps returning:

"This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access."

In my personal Gmail, in a Google Doc, I created a simple script that changes headings from Heading1 to Heading3 - no big deal.
It uses DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs()
When I try to run, it says "Authorization required"
I reveiew permissions
I select my account
I get "This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access."

I've tried like 20 different things to make this work.
I've done a dozen or so scripts before with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me so I can't reproduce your issue:

```
function testie() {
  let ps = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
  Logger.log(ps.length);
}
```